# Excel: One Cell (not range of cells) contains the same value multiple times. I need to count how many times that value exists in each cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lolyD.png)

Example:
In the attached screenshot, we see column G, "Tags". This is exported data from a program.  I want the count of "Testing Shadow" phrase or "Shadow" word to roll into a new formula column F, "Shadow".

Taking this same example and with a working formula, I would expect the entries from G464 to produce a "3" in F464.  G465 would produce a "0" in F465.  G466 would produce a "1" in F466.

I've attempted:
=COUNTIF([@Tags],(FIND("Shadow",[@Tags])))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick search I've found this solution:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/formulas-to-count-occurrences-in-excel

So in your case you should put in cell F464:

```
=(LEN(G464)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G464;"Shadow";"")))/LEN("Shadow")
```

and copy it to the cells below (the formula should change regarding the line)